# How should I group these variables?

Tags: c, coding-style, performance

I have a shape that will be defined by:

```
char s_type;
char color;
double height;
double width;
```

These variables are scanned in from a request string sent to my server and passed into my printing function, which then prints out the shape. Currently they are just local variables sitting in my `main()`; however, I was wondering if there would be any advantage in creating a struct containing these variables, and then passing the struct to my printing function? or how else might I improve my program's structure/style, would passing a struct by reference have any kind of performance benefit if there were many requests and therefore many printing function calls?

```
printer(char st, char cr, double ht, double wd);

int main()
{
    // Other main functionality.

    char s_type;
    char color;
    double height;
    double width;

    sscanf (serv_req, "GET /%c/%c/%lf/%lf", &s_type, &color, &height, &width);

    printer(s_type, color, height, width);

    // Other main functionality.

    return 0;
}
```

It seemed "neater" if I had a struct or something that didn't leave me with declarations in the middle of everything else going on in main. I'm interested in structure/style as well as performance.

EDIT: didn't mean to put printer declaration inside main.

Comment: So what's stopping you from creating a struct if you think that'd help?

Comment: @Caleb: I wasn't sure if it would help or not, hence the question. It was just an idea, wanted to hear how others would group them etc.

Answer (score 2):

Style is pretty subjective; if using a struct makes the code look better to you, do it. Unless your `printer()` function is trivial the way you pass the data (struct or not, by reference or not) won't make a measurable difference.

Probably the best thing you could do for your code would be to break out the various parts of `main()` indicated by the "other main functionality" comments into separate functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use macros to achieve something like:

```
sscanf4(serv_req,"GET /%c/%c/%lf/%lf", typ, col, h, w, char, char, double, double);
printer(typ, col, h, w);
```

As for performance, using structs won't make much difference. You can double check that adding for-loop, looping though whole thing 10000 times, and calling timeGetTime() to measure time spent. Usually possibilities to optimize are not where you think they are.

Comment: Edited, I didn't mean to imply that the writing out the types in my printer() function was the problem. That was just a typo :S So, you don't think that passing a struct into printer() as one argument instead of four is of any consequence?

Comment: most likely no. after all it's not like some time critical image-processing. btw another ways to achieve same optimization is adding __forceinline attribute to printer function, or changing arguments to "(const char&, const char&, const double&, const double&)".